# PHPMailer,SMTP Error Could not connect to smtp host

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer, sha1

I have a simple member management on my site. It is based on the php session. Where users can login, change password, request for a new password, logout. All of these functions works well when I perform in my PC. Request for a new password works fine and mail sent successfully, new password is received in mail.

If I try to request for a new password in mobile(iPhone) (Opened the website through local ip) I get the following error SMTP Error Could not connect to smtp host Mail not sent, try again!. But, when i do the same in my PC mail was sent successfully. When I try in samsung mobile (S4), it works sometime and sometimes error.

mymail function receives the to address, subject, message and from address from a call in other php file. Message contains the username and new password, and it is html code.

I'll explain you clearly with the code..

This is the  send_mail.php. "mymail" function is called from another php file.

```
<?php
//include phpmailer
require_once ('class.phpmailer.php');
function mymail($mto, $msub, $mbody, $mfrom) {
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail -> IsSMTP();
$mail -> SMTPAuth = true;
$mail -> SMTPSecure = "tls";

$mail -> Host = "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com";
$mail -> Username = "Provided by Amazon SES";
$mail -> Password = "Provided by Amazon SES";

$mail -> SetFrom("$mfrom", '');
//from (verified email address)
$mail -> Subject = "$msub";
$body = "$mbody";
$body = eregi_replace("[\]", '', $body);
$mail -> MsgHTML($body);
$mail -> AddAddress("$mto", "");

if ($mail -> Send()) {
    return 1;
} else {
    echo "<br> Mail not sent, try again!";
    return 0;
}
}
?>
```

And, yes I am sending mail from and to the verified email in Amazon SES. I have tryed to edit the php code. Removed the sha1 function from other php file and no use. I think the problem is in this function.Generally php is server side, but, will the php processor works differently when accessed from mobile or pc? I've been trying from yesterday night. Done enough research in google. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are vast numbers of duplicates of this question. Nearly all of them can be solved by simply [reading the docs that PHPMailer provides](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). You're also using an old version of PHPMailer. As @sanki says, you should also set `Port = 587`.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated, but the issue is not about the update. Here the email entered is case sensitive. In my mobile while entering email first letter is capital. That is an issue! Found it only when I updated it. I have traced the log from starting to end. Then I figured out the case sensitive is an issue. Btw Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating the PHPMailer. That should fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try adding port number:

```
$ mail-> Port = 587; // amazon ses port number
```

In addition to that you can use:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
```

To get the debugging info.

It could be due to lack of SSL support in PHP also. Which can be enabled by using:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just dealing with the same sendmail php function. Some of the things that you have to note:

1. Some servers like GMAIL require you to set some settings before you allow untrusted applications (in this case your script) from login in to your account. You are using amazon, but i believe they work on similar security settings.
2. Make sure you have the correct host and port number.
3. Make sure your form always passes the correct information across. If one field isn't passed correctly, email will NOT be sent nonetheless.
4. Mobile, pc or samsung should work the same way, as they have access to the same files and browser support for sendmail is likely the same.

Comment: Thanks, Its all about the case sensitive.  In my mobile while entering email first letter is capital. That is an issue!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it, it is very simple.

Email here is case sensitive! Tried changing the starting letter from capital to small. Its fixed.Thanks for all who have tried to answer the issue!